# php date next week according to today

Tags: php, date

I want to show next week, if its after Thursday 13:00 it should return +2 week(the week after next week). this code works fine if its not weekend. it gives wrong startday after Friday. what can cause this?

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');

if ($current_time < strtotime('thursday this week 13:00')) {
    $week_start = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week next monday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $week_end = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('next week next sunday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
} else {
    if (date('N') > 5) {
        $week_start = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 week next monday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    } else {
        $week_start = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('next week next monday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    }

    $week_end = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 week next sunday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')))); 
} 

return $week_start." - ".$week_end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement has 3 brances even if you are saying that you are only testing for the date to be before or after Thursday 13:00.

It seems that `+2 week next monday` should be `next week next monday`, while
the line that reads `next week next monday` are probably never executed.

The code can also be simplified like this:

```
if ($current_time < strtotime('thursday this week 13:00')){
    $week_start = strtotime('monday next week');
}else{
    $week_start = strtotime('monday +1 week');
}

$week_end = strtotime('next sunday', $week_start);

return date("Y/m/d", $week_start)." - ".date("Y/m/d", $week_end);
```